# Is there a way to designate that an app opens on a specific display in OsX?

Tags: macos

I need my application to launch in a specific display (assuming there's more than one display) and go to full screen.  The app  itself is a Flash app, but I can write a native executable for the mac to launch it, I just don't know how to dictate which display it opens in.  This is a fairly simple thing to do in Windows, I was hoping there's a mac analog.

[EDIT] poking around COCOA app development seems to suggest that the NSScreen object is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for CGDisplayBounds, CGDisplayCapture and CGGetOnlineDisplayList. With these functions you can get the list of displays, find the display bounds to create your window. And even capture the display so only your app can use it.